# Lint-staged + vitest - running related tests as precommit hook takes too much time

Tags: vitest, husky, lint-staged

My configuration in package.json looks like this.
I have two projects (one in app directory, another in backoffice directory)

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cd app && yarn start",
    "test": "cd app && vitest related --run --passWithNoTests",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "test-backoffice": "cd backoffice && vitest related --run --passWithNoTests"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)": [
      "yarn test",
      "yarn test-backoffice",
    ]
  },
```

If I remove `related` from test commands it goes very quickly but doesn't execute proper tests (ex. change in fullname.ts doesn't trigger execution of tests inside fullname.test.ts).

But with `related` it takes too much time, and it doesn't sum up correctly. Here is what I can see in the console. Notice that duration is much higher than sum of all parts.

```
Duration  19.14s (transform 496ms, setup 121ms, collect 787ms, tests 11ms, environment 224ms, prepare 49ms)
```